# Database mongoDB or mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb

I'm creating a search engine for deals, disscounts and coupons. First with my engine I collect deals from some sites and write that deals into database. So an records have a:

records: name,dissount,price,latitude,longitude

Now i'm using mysql but is my search engine will be faster if I use mongodB becouse all results in is similar json format

What is better solution if I have 1,000,000 records mysql or mongoDB ? I need faster searching.

http://test.pluspon.com

Comment: how to optimize my web app for faster working or problem is slow server?

Comment: Please mention your criteria for querying as other NoSQL databases can also help if you mention it.

Comment: Truely discussed a trillion times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case MongoDB would indeed be faster. 
You can easy implement processing with multiple mongos in sharded environments, there would not be any blocking and even more performance gain for your use case.

But keep in mind that speed benchmarks and fast data processing is not the only thing you should care about. MongoDB is still at very young age compared to more mature enterprise databases. But for your named use case i would advise to go with it.

Also as commented there are other NoSQL databases that could help you even better in some cases. Read up [this blog](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/) for more understanding